# minecraft command block problem "snowball"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
execute @a[score_HoldSnowball_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=Snowball,rm=3,r=4] Snowball 1
```

but it doesn't execute the code and instead says:

```
[13:59:43] Failed to execute 'scoreboard players set @e[type=Snowball,rm=3,r=4] Snowball 1' as xXElite_PythonXx
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your command is fine; something is wrong with your setup, or what you're expecting the command to do. Be aware that that message will appear if there's not *currently* a snowball 3-4 blocks from you. You may wish to add `/say @e[score_snowball_min=1]` on a repeating command block to test if the snowball's score is being set.

Comment: checked the /say, there must be something wrong with how its set up

Comment: this code is to make sure snowballs do damage, but only specific ones

Comment: heres the code:

Comment: /scoreboard players set @a HoldSnowball 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:snowball",tag:{display:{Name:"shuriken",Lore:["_____"]},ench:[]}}}                                                                                                                /execute @a[score_HoldSnowball_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=Snowball,rm=3,r=4] Snowball 1

Comment: execute @e[type=Snowball,score_Snowball_min=1] ~ ~ ~ effect @e[r=2] wither 1 1 true

Comment: `ench:[]` - This tests for an empty enchantments list, but I don't think it exists at all if there's no enchantments.

Comment: What Minecraft version are you running this command in?